# Excel VBA 'Updating' Function

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble getting this code to execute. The purpose of the code is to 'Update' an existing row in a database spreadsheet, based on data input from a userform in Excel. Because there are so many rows in the database spreadsheet, I wrote the code to first copy data to an empty spreadsheet and then move it to the database spreadsheet..however, when I run this code I keep getting the error message that's set to show at the end of the code. Do you have any insight into where my errors are?

```
Private Sub UpdateButton_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'new
Dim copySheet As Worksheet 'new
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet 'new
Dim f As Range, v

v = Trim(Me.TextBox1.Value)

Set copySheet = Worksheets("COPY AREA") 'NEW
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Database Entry Sheet") 'new

copySheet.Activate 'new

If Len(v) = 0 Then
     Msgbox "Run number cannot be blank", vbExclamation, "No"
     Exit Sub
End If

 Set f = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A").Find(What:=v, _
                                      lookat:=xlWhole)
 If Not f Is Nothing Then
     If Msgbox("Are you sure you want to update the record?", _
                  vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "UpdateRecord") = vbYes Then
 
 'Transfer information
        Cells(4, 1).Value = TextBox1.Value
        Cells(4, 2).Value = textbox2.Value
        Cells(4, 3).Value = textbox3.Value
        Cells(4, 4).Value = textbox4.Value
        Cells(4, 5).Value = textbox5.Value
        Cells(4, 6).Value = textbox6.Value
        Cells(4, 7).Value = textbox7.Value
        Cells(4, 8).Value = textbox8.Value
        Cells(4, 9).Value = textbox9.Value
        Cells(4, 11).Value = textbox11.Value
        Cells(4, 12).Value = textbox12.Value
        Cells(4, 13).Value = textbox13.Value
        Cells(4, 14).Value = textbox14.Value
        Cells(4, 17).Value = textbox17.Value
        Cells(4, 18).Value = textbox18.Value
        Cells(4, 19).Value = textbox19.Value
        Cells(4, 20).Value = textbox20.Value
        Cells(4, 21).Value = textbox21.Value
        Cells(4, 25).Value = textbox25.Value
        Cells(4, 26).Value = textbox26.Value
        Cells(4, 27).Value = textbox27.Value
        Cells(4, 28).Value = textbox28.Value
        Cells(4, 29).Value = textbox29.Value
        Cells(4, 33).Value = textbox33.Value
        Cells(4, 34).Value = textbox34.Value
        Cells(4, 35).Value = textbox35.Value
        Cells(4, 36).Value = textbox36.Value
        Cells(4, 37).Value = textbox37.Value
        Cells(4, 41).Value = textbox41.Value
        Cells(4, 42).Value = textbox42.Value
        Cells(4, 43).Value = textbox43.Value
        Cells(4, 44).Value = textbox44.Value
        Cells(4, 45).Value = textbox45.Value
    
        copySheet.Range("A4:BC4").Copy
            pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
          
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
        pasteSheet.Activate
            
          With f.EntireRow
              .Cells(1) = v  
              .Cells(2).value = textbox2.Value
              .Cells(3).Value = textbox3.Value
              .Cells(4).Value = textbox4.Value
              .Cells(5).Value = textbox5.Value
              .Cells(6).Value = textbox6.Value
              .Cells(7).Value = textbox7.Value
              .Cells(8).Value = textbox8.Value
              .Cells(9).Value = textbox9.Value
              .Cells(11).Value = textbox11.Value
              .Cells(12).Value = textbox12.Value
              .Cells(13).Value = textbox13.Value
              .Cells(14).Value = textbox14.Value
              .Cells(17).Value = textbox17.Value
              .Cells(18).Value = textbox18.Value
              .Cells(19).Value = textbox19.Value
              .Cells(20).Value = textbox20.Value
              .Cells(21).Value = textbox21.Value
              .Cells(25).Value = textbox25.Value
              .Cells(26).Value = textbox26.Value
              .Cells(27).Value = textbox27.Value
              .Cells(28).Value = textbox28.Value
              .Cells(29).Value = textbox29.Value
              .Cells(33).Value = textbox33.Value
              .Cells(34).Value = textbox34.Value
              .Cells(35).Value = textbox35.Value
              .Cells(36).Value = textbox36.Value
              .Cells(37).Value = textbox37.Value
              .Cells(41).Value = textbox41.Value
              .Cells(42).Value = textbox42.Value
              .Cells(43).Value = textbox43.Value
              .Cells(44).Value = textbox44.Value
              .Cells(45).Value = textbox45.Value
          End With
      End If
 Else
     Msgbox "not found - '" & v & "'"
 End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Sounds like the `Find` didn't find `v`. Make sure you specify `LookIn` as well.

Comment: Maybe try setting `LookIn` argument to `xlValues`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need to copy the data first to copysheet and then paste the data in the database sheet..You just can take the data in database sheet. And you should use a for loop for taking the data( As you have 45 textbox)..And i don't understand that what is the purpose of the f.entirerow ....(this section)? Sorry i want to comment in the post but i don't have enough reputation..